# What are the best playing styles for each nation in RUSE?

Tags: ruse

I have been playing RUSE recently and am trying each nation. I find that playing the Germans seems to suit my play style best. But I have been smashed by the French and Russians. What are the most appropriate game-play styles for each nation in multiplayer ?

Comment: If you're gonna -1. Please say why....

Comment: Considering that RUSE is a real-time-strategy, I might guess that the downvote comes from the subjective notion that there exists a "best nation". Most of these games are designed in a fashion such that there is no one-true-best, especially for a multiplayer setting. Rather, the best tends to be what works the most for the individual player, making it very subject to interpretation.

Comment: @Gracenote. Fair enough that all the nations are balanced for game play. I have modified my question to reflect your input and  Elpezmuerto great response +1 for Elpez!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First off, its all about play style. The best faction is the one that best matches you! For example, if you like aerial units, the United Kingdom is the way to go.**

I will try my best to match RUSE factions with other factions from other strategy games to draw similarities. Please note I do not consider this a great answer but unlike Starcraft 2 which has three races, Ruse has 6 which makes strategy more player dependent.

---

### United States

> Balance. The US military has a unit
> for every purpose, but doesn't excel
> with any given unit type. The US have
> average units and a high productivity
> thus "strength in numbers" is an
> advisable method of attack.

Think Terran from Starcraft or Orange Star from Advance Wars.

### Germany

> Quality Equipment. Though expensive to
> build, Germany's units are much more
> effective than those of other
> factions, with the exception of aerial
> units. Their artillery is also very
> accurate, but have shorter range as a
> result. Germany has many researchable
> and powerful units but they are quite
> expensive so tactics must be used to
> prevent the destruction of units

Think Protoss from Starcraft or Yellow Comment from Advance Wars

### French

> Defensive. Though their offensive
> capabilities are sub-par, they are
> well-equipped to resist enemy attacks,
> and require the least research to
> field their advanced units. They also
> have strong defensive bunkers from the
> get-go, recon units from their armor
> factory, but very weak aerial units

Think Kanbei (Yellow Comet) from Advance Wars

### United Kingdom

> Air Superiority. The UK has the best
> air units of the six factions, but
> have the second-worst tanks in the
> game (just ahead of Italy; see below)
> The British have unique Recon bunkers
> which extends their effective defense
> perimeter

Think Eagle (Green Earth) from Advance Wars

### U.S.S.R

> Strength. Powerful, slow-building
> tanks and artillery make up the
> majority of the Soviet war machine.
> The artillery is less accurate, but
> has much further range. Likewise,
> their bombers are slower, but carry a
> larger payload

Think Grit (Blue Moon) from Advance Wars...kinda

### Italy

> Speed/Superior Numbers. Italian units
> are weak, but cheap to build, take
> almost no time to construct, and are
> much faster than equivalent units from
> opposing factions. The Italian war
> machine relies almost completely on
> maneuverability and superior numbers.

Think Zerg from Starcraft, Colin (Blue Moon) from Advance Wars, or any faction that emphasis micro over macro

---

NOTE:: All quotes referenced from [here](http://ruse.wikia.com/wiki/Factions)

Answer (score 2):

I think Germany may be the best. It is expensive, but just buy a secondary base around depots and you're all set.

But be very careful what you buy. One good thing about their airplanes are that they are very fast. That's why I like their fighters and bombers, though. Their prototype is very good though. I like their whirlwinds. Their panzers are not worth it in the armor base unless you have over 8, you're all right.

Your worst enemy might be either Russia or UK because of their air and artillery. Your control might be Italy.

On center gravity and control the center if you can with a secondary headquarters.

Comment: It was my style. i like germany better than uk now. i tried out there heavies and aircraft and it was beast. thanks yo.

Comment: i lost man. didnt have the money for the tanks just did not work for me i will stick with america.

Comment: alright, hope you get better at Germany now. try out there anti tanks and prototypes to.

Answer (score 2):

Germany has expensive and unorganized stuff. Russia may not be as strong, but suits me well. Cheap barracks, expensive research on heavy infantry, but tough, cheap and armored AA, strong tanks and long range and very accurate, Russia could be the most helpful nation in 1939 too. I also think they have okay aircraft as well.

America also has the most absolutely best Anti-Air and tanks, try their armor artillery M40, it's amazing!  Their bases are balanced, tanks, AA, and artillery, just never try to play against Italy, as you don't stand a chance.  The Pershing is far range and the most powered heavy out there, other than the King Tiger.  $40 to purchase and $75 to research.

Comment: yeah well i like italy!! you dont know how to use it thats why!!!!

Comment: so use it wisely...

Comment: Although you explain some of the basics very well, there is a error in your statements. I've gone toe to toe with Germany's highest tanks while using USA's Super Pershings. It's a pretty even battle. Maybe you know, with the introduction of Japan, I'm having a difficult time distinguishing if Japan of UK has the better aerial units (Fighters, Fighter Bombers)